# Can this if-else-else logic be rewritten into something neater?

Tags: c#, .net, boolean-logic

Could I write the following logic in a simpler, more easy-to-read way? The below does what I need, but it is very messy:

```
if (IsChanged == true)
{
    return;
}

// Executed when the close (x) button is pressed,
// as the Status string is not yet set to a real value...
else if (Status == "" && IsChanged == false) 
{
    CancelClose();
}

// saving logic falls to here...
else if (IsChanged == false && Status == "saving") 
{
    IsChanged = false;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `== (true|false)` is of the devil. Of the devil, I say!

Comment: Yes, go with `!IsChanged` over `IsChanged == False`

Comment: Use string.Empty not "" to avoid unnecessary object creation

Comment: where tested, IsChanged can never be false, so this is uneccessary test!

Answer (score 20):

```
if (isChanged) return;

switch (Status) {
   case "": 
       CancelClose(); 
       break;
   case "saving": 
       // IsChanged = false;
       break;
}
```

This is about as neat as it gets. Note that because you return if isChanged is true you can further on always assume that isChanged is false.

Comment: I think that this is the most effective solution, fixing both sides.

Comment: "if (isChanged == true)" can be rewritten as "if (isChanged)".

Comment: could save the `== true` part

Comment: I didnt think! I just copied his ischanged == true :(

Answer (score 12):

This is a bit cleaner:

```
if (IsChanged)
{

}
else if (Status == "saving")
{

}
else if (Status == "")
{

}
else
{

}
```

I would recommend you use an `enum` to represent the status. This will allow your code to be strongly typed.

```
public enum Status
{
    Closing,
    Saving,
    Changed,
}
```

Then you can use a nice `switch` statement to decide what action to take.

```
switch (_status)
{
    case Status.Saving:
        break;
    case Status.Closing:
        break;
    case Status.Changed:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't check Status == "" in the else case

Answer (score 4):

```
if(IsChanged)
  return;

if(Status == "saving")
{
    // save      
}
else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Status))
{
    CancelClose();    
}
```

Comment: Absolutely. No point checking if `isChanged` is false when it would have returned if it were true.

Comment: Doesn't check Status == "" in the else case

Comment: This would fail if more options for status are available

Comment: Thought about it some more and edited the answer to be true to the original implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Since you return if IsChanged==true, you don't need it in the other ifs.

```
    if (IsChanged == true)
        return;

    switch (Status)
    { 
       case "":
        CancelClose();
        break;
       case "saving":
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I tend to avoid the `switch` statement for a small number of strings.

Comment: I think the advantages of the switch statement in this case is that. You can easily see how the flow will be depending on the Status (and no other variables), and one can easily imagine adding more cases depending on new values of Status.

Answer (score 1):

yes:

```
   if (IsChanged) return;
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Status)) CancelClose();
```

Comment: That's incomplete. You're missing a spot for the actual saving logic -- which you don't want to fall into if CancelClose is called.

Comment: What I have above is equivilent to the sample presented, as nothing happens in the last block anyway. (unless the status property has some side effects besides returning a string value, which would be very very bad...)

Answer (score 1):

- cut the first else if to just if. If IsChanged is true the "else" will never be reached.
- remove the IsChanged==false from your other ifs because they are always true.
- Think about enums instead of strings for your status.

I'd recommend:

```
if (IsChanged)
{
      return;
}

if (CurrentStatus == Status.None) 
{
     CancelClose();
     return;
}

if (CurrentStatus == Status.Saving) 
{
  //     IsChanged = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(!IsChanged) {
        if (Status == "saving") // saving logic falls to here...
        {
            //     IsChanged = false;
        } 
        else if (Status == "") // Executed when the close (x) button is pressed, as the Status string is not yet set to a real value...
        {
            CancelClose();
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be simplifed in to

```
    if (IsChanged)
    {
        return;
    }

    else if (Status == "") // Executed when the close (x) button is pressed, as the Status string is not yet set to a real value...
    {
        CancelClose();
    }

    else if (Status == "saving") // saving logic falls to here...
    {
        //     IsChanged = false;
    }
```

You do not need the == True in the first check, as it already is true or false. you do not need to check for false in the other choices because if it is not true it must be false.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (IsChanged) return;

if (Status == "saving")
{
  //IsChanged = false;
}
else if (Status = "")
{
  CancelClose();
}
```

I'd avoid beginning your variable names with uppercase.

Comment: You can take everything out of the large else block.

Comment: Maybe `IsChanged` and 'Status' are a properties?

Comment: These are property names, and property names usually begin with a capital letter. The alternative would be something like a private _isChanged.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (IsChanged) 
   return;

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Status)) // better use this unless you would like a
   CancelClose();                 // nullPointerException

else if (Status.equals("Saving"))
   // whatever you want for save
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with c#, but [it supports the conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

Since I'm not familiar with c#, I won't try to re-write your code, but in any case, the ternary operator can lead to pleasing concision in some places.